# Incorrect course details are being echoed

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a basic mysqli code below where it performs a query to select Course number and Course Name from database and display it in a drop down menu.

```
    $sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course ORDER BY CourseId"; 

    $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $sqlstmt->execute(); 

    $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

    $courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

    $courseHTML = "";  
    $courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop" onchange="getModules();">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

    $outputcourse = ""; 
    while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
    { 
    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

    $outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseno .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";

    } 

    $courseHTML .= '</select>';  

    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Course: <?php echo $courseHTML; ?></th>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Course and Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>
</form>

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {

    $assessmentform = "<div id='lt-container'>
<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
{$outputcourse}
</form>
</div>";

echo $assessmentform;

...

?>
```

Now lets say the drop down menu contains these courses below:

```
INFO101 - Information Communication Technology
INFO102 - Computing
```

For some strange reason no matter which course I choose from the drop down menu, when I click on the the submit button, the echo it is suppose to output underneath the drop down menu always outputs the Course Number  and Course Name `INFO102 - Computing`. This is even though I selected the other option `INFO101 - Information Communication Technology` Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` loop, you are reinitializing `$outputcourse` on each iteration, rather than accumulating it into a long string. It therefore would only ever show the *last* item fetched in your loop.

```
// Initialize $outputcourse outside the loop:
$outputcourse = "";
while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
{ 
    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

    // Match the course in $_POST with the current fetch iteration and load $outputcourse
    if (isset($_POST['courses']) && $_POST['courses'] == $course)) {
      $outputcourse = "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseno .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Now, only the selected course will be loaded into `$outputcourse`.  Hopefully you have included some other inputs in your `$assessmentform` which are not shown above, because as it is now you have just wrapped a `<p>` inside a `<form>` with no associated inputs.

Comment: Can I ask you a very quick question, how come that after I have made the change that it displays the `$outputcourse` twice on the screen? It displays `INFO101 ....` twice and not once? Code updated

Comment: @user1819709 I can't say.  Unless you have duplicate rows in your database, there's nothing above that would cause it to show twice.  Debug by echoing all the values `$courseno $coursename` as they are fetched in the `while` loop to see what the DB is producing.  Otherwise, I can't see what you have in the `...` after `echo $assessmentform`.

Comment: There are no statements in your while loop that could cause output, only variable assignments. You need to debug either by putting in little echo statements like `echo "Before while loop"; `echo "inside while loop";` etc... or view your page source in the browser to see where in your markup the output is happening to narrow it down.

Comment: It is no duplicate rows in database. It is because that because the `$outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseno .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";` is in the while loop, it will display both courses for `$outputcourse`. This is what I found out when echoing `$courseno $coursename` as it outputted both courses. But if I move that `$outputmodule` line outside the while loop and change `$courseno $coursename` to `$dbCourseNo $dbCourseName`, then Im back to square one where it displays the wrong course

Comment: @user1819709 Then I am not understanding what output you _are supposed to be getting_ because all along I thought you wanted to accumulate those courses in the while loop. What is it _supposed to print_?

Comment: It is suppose to print the course you have selected from the drop down menu. The drop down menu contains the list of all the courses while the `$outputcourse` variable prints out the course you have selected from the drop down menu

Comment: At no point were you checking the value of `$_POST['courses']`. I moved that into the fetch loop to populate `$outputcourse` with the values that match `$_POST['courses']`